# How can I use package xpath-ts + xmldom in typescript?

Tags: xml, typescript, xpath

I want use xmldom + xpath in typescript. For xpath package are none type. So I installed package xpath-ts + xmldom-ts.

But the examples on package documentation not working.

example:

```
import { DOMParserImpl as dom } from 'xmldom-ts';
import * as xpath from 'xpath-ts';
 
const xml = '<book><title>Harry Potter</title></book>';
const doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml);
const nodes = xpath.select('//title', doc);
 
console.log(nodes[0].localName + ': ' + nodes[0].firstChild.data);
console.log('Node: ' + nodes[0].toString());
```

on execution I got the error:

```
src/importDWD.ts:100:43 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Document' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
  Type 'Document' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': observers, addObserver, delObserver

100     const nodes = xpath.select('//title', doc);
                                              ~~~
```

and a lot of other compile errors

How can I use xpath in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Install xmldom package + types and the xpath-ts package

```
npm install --save-dev @types/xmldom
```

Now you can find a XML node by xpath expression:

```
let xml: string = '<book><title>Harry Potter</title></book>';

const parser = new xmldom.DOMParser()
let doc: Document = parser.parseFromString(xml)

let nodes: Node[] = xpath.select('//title',doc) as Node[]

console.log(nodes[0].nodeName + ': ' + nodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
console.log('Node: ' + nodes[0].toString());
```

output

```
title: Harry Potter
Node: <title>Harry Potter</title>
```

and the evaluate function

```
let xml: string = '<book><title>Harry Potter</title></book>';

const parser = new xmldom.DOMParser()
let doc: Document = parser.parseFromString(xml)

let result: XPathResult = xpath.evaluate("/book/title",
    doc, null, xpath.XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)

let node = result.iterateNext();
while (node) {
    console.log(node.nodeName + ': ' + node.firstChild.nodeValue);
    console.log('Node: ' + node.toString());

    node = result.iterateNext();
}
```